# Google new spreadsheet Split() function bug?

Tags: google-sheets

try this.

in cell A1 `10/8/2013 Mike1, 2013, 0`

now `Split(A1,",")`

now change A1 and add a colon `10/8/2013 Mike:1, 2013, 0`

`Split(A1,",")` ... notice how `Mike:1` is gone. Bug?

I need to split something with a colon in it and it is chopping off part of the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that "10/8/2013 Mike:1" is interpreted as a date, it seems to be something like: "dd/mm/yyyy hhhh:mm". (if you change the display of the first cell to raw text you'll see he is giving you a number: 41496).

try this formula:

```
=arrayformula(SUBSTITUTE(arrayformula(split(REGEXREPLACE(A1;":";"#@#");","));"#@#";":"))
```

in a easier way: As I suppose you can't change the way it's displayed, the possible workaround that I see here is to first split around the ":", then split with the "," and then join the two first elements.

Comment: i like your solution better. I have this really ghetto solution which is I first add a random letter like "a" to the front, then split it, then I use `mid` function to remove the first letter. It worked, but i didn't realize that the colon makes it treat the data like a date format. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this issue, either with function SPLIT or with *Split text into columns...* and with or without formatting as `dd/mm/yyyy hhhh:mm`.

Select A1, Data > Split text into columns... is all that is required.